# LINQ Take syntax

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have written some LINQ to simulate an SQL GroupBy statement (see below).  However, I also need to only consider only the last 10 settingIds before doing my group by.  I think I would use Take to do this, but what would be the correct syntax in my statement?

```
var settings2 = from s in dc.SystemSettings
                where s.campConfig.campaignType == campType
                      && s.campId != campId
                      && s.settingKey == ticket.setting.Key
                orderby s.settingId descending
                group s by s.settingValue
                into grp
                select new
                {
                    SettingValue = grp.Key,
                    SettingCount = grp.Select(x => x.settingValue).Count()
                };
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code better to make it more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
var settings2 = from sOuter in 
    (from s in dc.SystemSettings
    where s.campConfig.campaignType == campType
      && s.campId != campId
      && s.settingKey == ticket.setting.Key
    orderby s.settingId descending
    select s).Take(10)
    group sOuter by sOuter.settingValue
    into grp
    select new
    {
      SettingValue = grp.Key,
      SettingCount = grp.Select(x => x.settingValue).Count()
    };
```